# Diagonalisable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}.$$

Show that

1) $A$ is diagonalisable if $(a - d)^2  + 4 bc > 0$

2) $A$ is not diagonalisable if $(a - d)^2 + 4 bc < 0$

Comment: Do you mean to ask about diagonalizability over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes @ Git Gud..

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial is

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-a&-b\\-c&x-d\end{vmatrix}=x^2-(a+d)x+(ad-bc)$$

The above quadratic's discriminant is

$$\Delta=(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)=(a-d)^2+4bc$$

Now, what does having positive discriminant imply for the roots of a quadratic? And what does having two different eigenvalues imply about diagonalizing (or not) a $\;2\times2\;$ matrix? And what if no eigenvalues exist?

Comment: Is it possible that any matrix can have complex eigenvalues ?

Comment: @IdeedRafiqi Of course,,,but it *must* be defined over the complex field  or, at least, over some subfield of the complex that allows an extension to some field containing the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at the characteristic polynomial and see what those conditions imply.